# Regex Comma Separated Phone Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to generate a regex which would match the following sequence-

`+91123456789,+41123456789,+21123456789....` and so on, there is no limit of phone numbers.

Basically the usage is to validate the phone numbers which users may add, phone number can be multiple and need to be separated by commas, I am already removing the empty spaces which users may add, so no worry for that.

I am not good with regex and have created the following regex but it doesn't matches the preceding phone numbers, means the whole string of phone numbers do not match-

```
^\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9},\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}$
```

I need to validate the user input using javascript or jquery.

Valid Phone number should be having country code like +91 or +21 etc country code can be of one or two digits, then the number of digits need to be 7 to 9.

I anyone could help, it would be highly appreciable, I have spent lot of time on this one.

Comment: I find www.regex101.com to be a great resource.  You haven't specified in your question what you consider a valid phone number to be, what makes a valid number?

Comment: Why not just `\+\d{11}/g`?

Comment: @jack, you're right, I have been testing the specified regex on regex101.com, I am adding the format of valid phone number in question. thanks

Comment: Perhaps split on `,` and examine each individually, that way you can easily tell the the user the specific one that needs correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To validate the whole string handling mulitple values sepparated by comma just add an group with * multiplier:

```
^\+\d{8,11}(,\+\d{8,11})*$
```

Comment: thanks, your solution worked perfectly, I have added the regex demo link in your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirements correctly, the following regex should work

```
\+\d{9,11}
```

However, you can separate the country code out, for if you need to allow for `(+44)xxxxxxxxx`

```
\+\d{2}\d{7,9}
```

if the requirement is to allow for 1 country code as well, adjust the regex to the following

```
 \+\d{1,2}\d{7,10} //I think to 10, not sure on their numbers
```

You can update the ranges as you see fit :)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rJ4wM7/1

Comment: I believe you should expect countries with only one digit for country code, USA is +1, and also he asked for a way to add multiple phones and separate them with commas

Comment: @Luizgrs, yes I have updated in my question some countries have single digit country code and some have two digits, thanks

Comment: @ManikArora Updated my answer

Comment: I can't see what the difference would be between `\d{2}\d{7,9}` and simply `\d{9,11}`?

Comment: @freefaller there isnt, you are completely right, makes for better understanding :)  Allowing to add a separator in between (ie. `(+44)12123123123`)

Comment: @Johan, can you please test with this string, I think this is also getting matched- +911234567899,+91123456789,+91123456789999, please see the last one.